Python monorepo packaging, using Poetry
I want to organize my Python source code into a monorepo, with the below basic structure:
projectrootdir
  - libraryone
    - pyproject.toml
    - README
    - src/orgname/libraryone
      - __init__.py
      - somemodule.py
  - webapi
    - pyproject.toml
    - README
    - src/organame/webapi
      - __init__.py
      - apimodule.py

In the apimodule.py file, I want to use modules from libraryone like so:
from orgname.libraryone import somemodule

As of now, I can't do this. Instead, the below works:
from libraryone.src.orgname.libraryone import somemodule

In the pyproject.toml file for webapi, I have added the below:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
libraryone = {path = "../libraryone"}

How can I organize and configure this to achieve what I want? Do I need configurations directly under projectroodir?
